# i create a bot can change my roles away but it get err

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i create a bot can change my roles away but it get err
when i am a roles
it can delete a roles
and change to b roles
and change back to a roles

```
myname.add_roles(rolesID)
```

i open dev mod and use my descord and set myname = myid
but i get

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

so i change myid to my discord username and #
i get

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually get the member **object** from your id.

For example:

```
guild_obj = client.get_guild(Your Guild Id here)
member_obj = guild_obj.get_member(Your Member Id here)
await member_obj.add_roles(rolesID)
```